# How come this variable echo's as 16?

Tags: php

```
$body = "Artist: " + $artist + "Size: " + $size + "Time: " + $time + "Concept: " + $concept + "Time: " + $time + "Mod: " + $mod + "Details: " + $details;
```

When I try to echo this variable, all that comes out is '16.'

Can you guys help?

Answer (score 4):

The concatenation operator in PHP is the `.` not the `+`

```
$body = "Artist: " . $artist . "Size: " . $size . "Time: " . $time . "Concept: " . $concept . "Time: " . $time . "Mod: " . $mod . "Details: " . $details;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the concatenation operator is `.`, not `+`

So:

```
$body = "Artist: " . $artist . "Size: " . $size . "Time: " . $time . "Concept: " . $concept ."Time: " . $time . "Mod: " . $mod . "Details: " . $details;
```